# How to detect first or last element iterating over a container?

Tags: c++, stl

How to do the following in more stylish/short way?

```
for(i=container.begin(); i!=container.end(); ++i) {
    if (i!=container.begin()) {
        cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << *i;
    j=i;
    if (++j==container.end()) {
        cout << "!" << endl; 
    }
}
```

Solutions like [foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498455/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-container/498483#498483) are acceptable (actions on first and **last** elements need to be configurable, though).

P.S.
There are many answers that are handling first element, but not last. Here is what I mean by *handling* last element:

```
for(i=container.begin(); i!=container.end(); ++i) {
    j=i;
    if (i==container.begin()) {
        cout << "[" << *i << "]" << endl;
    } else if (++j==container.end()) {
        cout << ", (" << *i << ")" << "!" << endl; 
    } else {
         cout << ", " << *i;
    }
}
```

Don't you think it's very easy to handle first element outside the cycle body? The real problem is the last one! I'm sorry for not being able to clarify the important point asking the question. I think I'll just accept the top ranked answer eventually.

Comment: I don't think your example is correct. container.end() is the element after the last. At the end of your forloop (for the last element) it gets incremented and becomes container.end() which is your end condition. Correct is `i+1 == container.end()`.

Comment: Is the `iterator + int` operation supported for non-random-access iterators?

Comment: Thirler did you comment on ++j variant or on the previous one? I've made some changes after Neil's bug report.

Comment: Thirler's comment applies to the current version, Basilevs.

@Mike: No, it's not, but std::advance will work for all input iterators.  I'm unsure whether it would work for input iterators in the purest sense, though, such as iterators that read values from a stream or file.

Comment: So Thriller, what is your point? It's true that j becomes container.end(), but I don't use element it points to. I only use *i.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost has [next / prior](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/utility/utility.htm) which can sometimes help in such situations.

```
for(i=container.begin(); i!=container.end(); ++i) {
    if (boost::next(i) == container.end()) {
         std::cout << "!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Although for this specific case, I'd simply output the first element, loop from second till last while always outputting the ',' and then output the '!' after the loop has ended. (as others have suggested already)

I don't see the point in moving the special cases inside the loop, and then checking inside the loop for them....

Comment: This is the best answer from my point of view. See updated question with clarification.

Answer (score 3):

My advice here would be: **there is no point in detecting anything within this loop !**

Since your special cases are at the beginning and the end of your container, it is easy to remove their processing from within the loop.

The following function will print the contents of any container class whose elements can be `<<`'ed to an `std::ostream`:

```
template < class Container >
void print(Container const & container)
{
    typename Container::const_iterator current = container.begin();
    typename Container::const_iterator const end = container.end();
    if (current != end)
    {
        std::cout << *current;
        for (++current; current != end; ++current)
        { 
            std::cout << ", " << *current;
        }
        std::cout << "!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: For cycle is better than while. The handling of the last element is missing though.

Comment: No, last element is processed correctly. end() return an iterator which shall never be dereferenced, it's past the end. Unless you intended not to print the '!' ?

Comment: My example don't demonstrate this, but the question clearly has requested special handling of the last element. I don't mean *(container.end()) here. I mean last valid element.

Comment: Hmmm the last element gets followed by a '!' if that's what you ask. If you call it on [1,2,3] you'll get "1, 2, 3!"... What did I miss ?

Comment: I'm sorry for my example, that really don't handle the last element in any way. I've edited the question adding a new example.

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
if (i==container.end()) {
    cout << "!" << endl; 
}
```

will never happen.

My own approach would be to use the container size (I think size() is now constant time for all Standard Library containers). Maintain a count in the loop and you are at the end when count == size() - 1, and at the beginning when count == 0, obviously.

Comment: i thought currently the standard only guaranteed O(n) for size for non random access containers? i'd still probably go for this unless profiling showed it was an issue

Comment: @jk There was  a discussion about this here  awhile back (which of course I can't find) - the only container which historically has not been O(1) for size is std::list, but there seems to have been a TC or something changing this - sorry not to be more helpful, perhaps someone else can confirm or deny this authoritatively?

Answer (score 2):

As `container` is not defined by you, I used the simplest - `vector`

```
template <class T>
string vector_join( const vector<T>& v, const string& token ){
  ostringstream result;
  for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++){
    if (i != v.begin()) result << token;
    result << *i;
  }
  return result.str();
}

//usage
cout << vector_join( container, ", " ) << "!";
```

Answer (score 1):

Shift the `++i` a bit:

```
i = container.begin();
while(i != container.end()) {
    if (i != container.begin()) {
        cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << *i;
    if (++i == container.end()) {
        cout << "!" << endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. Removing cycle condition and inserting break in the last if statement block would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

```
template < class TContainerType>
void print(TContainerType const & i_container)
  {
  typename TContainerTypeconst ::const_iterator current = i_container.begin();
  typename TContainerTypeconst ::const_iterator const end = i_container.end();
  if(current != end)
    {
    std::cout << *current++;
    while(current != end)
      std::cout << ", " << *current++;
     }
  std::cout << "!" << std::endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the second part out of the loop.

```
for(i=container.begin(); i!=container.end(); ++i) {
    if (i != container.begin()) {
        cout << ", ";
    }
    cout << *i;
}
cout << "!" << endl;
```

Comment: How do I use the last element then? i after the cycle points to end() which don't point to the last element.